# Cloud function making multiple database reads in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Cloud Function in Typescript which listens for a node change and then gets all the "bookings", taking the customer value and getting all the corresponding tokens in the "notifications" node which I will use to send the notifications. Below is what I have so far. It is a total mess I am lost.

```
async function getBookings(){
admin.database().ref("bookings") //how do i loop through all booking and return?
}

export const sendNotificationLatenessNew = functions.database.ref("bookings/{pushId}/checkOutTime")
.onWrite(event => {

//get all 'bookings' where cancelled is false

//use the customer field get all user id (customer) 

//loop through 'notifications' using the customer value to get tokens   

  var payload = {
        data:{
            username: "test",
            email:"dsfsgd@fdf.com"
        }
    };      

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice("e-pXqGoQRpk:APA91bEZJAuDSFfOmTZhBWCIDOGaEYIk2_bdAHaHKK9Yr7-iS7H34sj1YRxVpuSChAKQJ4q667zVf-0yNGGla7f7F1XNHU0ESZjxFfJIAIh_gqkybF2dY4eJQwlYqNJLamaLAfnyVSbj", payload)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log("success late sending message, " , response);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error late sending message, " , error);
    });

});
```

and here is my database
[image]